# Appcelerator: Multiple Subviews Syncing to Last Callback

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

I'm creating a custom menu with background images, styling, etc. so I created a separate menuTile view and controller and send it the background, title, and callback.  If I add multiple menuTiles using the Require tag, all tiles fire the callback of the last menuTile instead of their own individual one.  I'm confident there is no bug/typo in my code so maybe it's a misunderstanding of the Require tag or callbacks.  Please assist.

Menu.xml, Menu.js...

```
<View id="vwBody">
    <Require src="menuTile" id="menuTile1" />
    <Require src="menuTile" id="menuTile2" />
    <Require src="menuTile" id="menuTile3" />
</View>

function initializeMenuTiles() {
    $.menuTile1.initialize({
        backgroundImage: 'img1.jpg',
        title: 'Menu Tile 1',
        callback: btnMenuTile1Click,
    });
    $.menuTile2.initialize({
        backgroundImage: 'img2.jpg',
        title: 'Menu Tile 2',
        callback: btnMenuTile2Click,
    });
    $.menuTile3.initialize({
        backgroundImage: 'img3.jpg',
        title: 'Menu Tile 3',
        callback: btnMenuTile3Click,
    });
}
```

MenuTile.js...

```
$.initialize = function(args) {
    $.btnMenuTile.backgroundImage = '/images/' + args.backgroundImage;
    $.btnMenuTileLabel.text = args.title;

    if (args.callback) {
        btnMenuTileClicked_callback = args.callback;
    }
};

function btnMenuTileClick() {
    if (btnMenuTileClicked_callback) {
        btnMenuTileClicked_callback();
    }
}
```

So no matter what menuTile I click, btnMenuTile3Click will always fire.  If I don't provide a callback for menuTile3, then btnMenuTile2Click will always fire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see where you define btnMenuTileClicked_callback so it will then be in the module's global scope, which is shared between all instances.

Simply add this before the `$.initialize...` line:

```
var btnMenuTileClicked_callback;
```